# Split radio button values using jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split the Radio Button values from my form so I know what the option chosen is, as well as the price. The value before the | separator is the price and the value after the | is the option chosen.

```
<input type="radio" name="arm" value="50|1" id="split" required> Option: 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="arm" value="100|2" id="split" required> Option: 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="arm" value="150|3" id="split" required> Option: 3<br>

<input type="radio" name="mechanism" value="50|1"> Option: 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="mechanism" value="100|2"> Option: 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="mechanism" value="150|3"> Option: 3<br>

<input type="radio" name="base" value="50|1"> Option: 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="base" value="100|2"> Option: 2<br>

<input type="radio" name="fabric" value="50|1"> Option: 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="fabric" value="50|2"> Option: 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="fabric" value="50|3"> Option: 3<br>

<script>

    jQuery(":text[name='quantity'], :radio[name='arm'], :radio[name='mechanism'], :radio[name='base'], :radio[name='fabric']").change(function(){
    var arm = jQuery(":radio[name='arm']:checked");
    var arr = arm.split('|');
    var $mechanism = jQuery(":radio[name='mechanism']:checked");
    var $base = jQuery(":radio[name='base']:checked");
    var $fabric = jQuery(":radio[name='fabric']:checked");
    var $quantity = jQuery(":text[name='quantity']");
    if($arm.length ==1){
        var a = parseInt($arm.val(arr[0]), 10);
        var m = parseInt($mechanism.val(), 10);
        var b = parseInt($base.val(), 10);
        var f = parseInt($fabric.val(), 10);
        var q = parseInt($quantity.val(), 10);
        jQuery("#result").val((a + m + b + f) * q);
    }
    });

</script>
```

I am trying to split the values using:

```
var arm = jQuery(":radio[name='arm']:checked");
var arr = arm.split('|');
```

And passing that value as follows:

```
 var a = parseInt($arm.val(arr[0]), 10);
```

This does not work. I am no Jquery or Javascript guru, what should I do to make this work?

Comment: You should be using `var arr = arm.val().split('|');` or `var arm = jQuery(":radio[name='arm']:checked").val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`var arr = arm.split('|');`

You need to get the `value` of `arm` and split that.

`var arr = arm.val().split('|');`

Comment: Yes, so how do I do that?

Comment: This gives me Error: $arm is not defined. I am guessing the error has something to do with this line: var a = parseInt($arm.val(arr[0]), 10);

Comment: Try `parseInt(arr[0], 10);`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I worked that one out. It seems to be working now, but giving me total values that are not correct.

Comment: How can I "Print" out the values for each array?

Comment: For debugging? One way would be to just loop through all the values. I would recommend using a debugging tool like Firebug though, as it makes js debugging much easier.

Comment: Sorted, I had some incorrect variable names, all working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`var arm = jQuery(":radio[name='arm']:checked").val();`

`var arr = arm.split('|');`

Comment: This gives me Error: $arm is not defined

Comment: I am guessing the error has something to do with this line: var a = parseInt($arm.val(arr[0]), 10);